# how to embed SWRevealViewController in the middle of the app not in the start of the app in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I wrote this code in my Home controller which has a menu button. This controller comes after login. I have seen many examples that use `SWrevealViewController` as initial view controller but I am not sure how to use it in the middle of the app. In Home screen, I have this code

```
if revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}
```

Comment: Refer these two links. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SWRevealViewController and https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues

Comment: So you want to add swrevealViewController  ? what is your initial controller right now?

Comment: my initial view controller in Login and after login another controller then Home controller comes i want to attach swrevealViewController with Home controller